# Can using `friend` in C++ affect the generated bytecode?

Tags: c++, code-generation, friend, typechecking

Is `friend` resolved entirely during the typechecking phase, or does it affect the way the output code is generated? In other words, is that possible that adding a `friend` to my class can result in a different binary file?

If it might be up to the compiler, then I am asking about GCC and Clang.

Comment: I don't see why generated code would be different.

Comment: No, the C++ interpreter doesn't care

Comment: "can result in a different binary file?" Aside from having vs lacking a resulting executable?

Comment: "Bytecode" doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: A friend declaration only affects acccess protection, but a compiler is free to encode this in the generated code or data if it has any use for that information.

Comment: Generally, it will depend on the implementation  (say, the compiler or linker in a classic compile-link toolchain).  There is no particular requirement in the standard that use of `friend` affect the translated code (say, the binary/executable file) for either the class (that declares the `friend`) or the `friend` itself.   Equally, there is also no requirement that the translated code will be unaffected.   So, it is notionally *possible*, but will not necessarily happen.   The only way to know for sure would be to analyse the output from the compiler (or, possibly, its design documentation).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to test using GCC:

Let's create a simple program

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
private:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
//  friend class A; //Uncomment to make a friend!

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "World!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Then we just have to run these commands:

```sh
g++ -S main.cpp #create the listing for the friendless main.cpp
mv main.s main_no.s #rename it so we don't lose it
sed -ie 's/\/\/  friend class A;/    friend class A;/g' main.cpp
g++ -S main.cpp #replace the line so we now have a friend
diff main.s main_no.s
```

And as we can see by the empty output of `diff` , both files are exactly the same. As said in the comments of the question, compilers are free to encode any information the way they want so even though this test passes today, GCC could decide to include friend relationships in the .s files in the future, making this simplistic test fail.

In that case, you'd need to remove any information put by gcc in the .s file that's not actually instructions (they usually start with a dot in the file)

Comment: This doesn't prove that in a more complicated program there isn't a difference

Comment: @Caleth that's fair, I tried reading through GCC's source code to make sure complexity had nothing to do with it but it's pretty hard to follow, maybe GDB will help. I'll edit the answer/post another one when/if I find the info